# SBS 2003 R2 install errors

Tags: windows-server-2003

I just installed sbs2003 R2 as a learning lab box on my home network.  The install seemed to take quit a while with a bit of shuffling between disks 4 and 5.  The continue setup checklist showed the red x besides the exchange install and finally gave me an error about the "schema needing extending run, forest /adprep" and told me at the end that the install did not succeed.  After a longer than normal reboot it comes up and seems to be OK.

What logs do i need to check to see what went wrong?

Should i reinstall and try burning the iso's to new media?

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like its stopped somewhere at the end of the install (while populating the exchange database). Being a learning lab box, it shouldn't be too much or a worry.

I build a 2k3 SBS R2 playing box last week and didn't run into any errors like that. Check the event logs (Application and System), they might explain something. If all else fails, try reinstalling again. It is only a learning box, and I think I re-installed mine countless times over the years trying new things.

"Should i reinstall and try burning the iso's to new media?" Being the SBS series was never released as a downloadable ISO (like all there other os's) than you could also have a bad ISO. Might I suggest trying to play in a Virtual Machine environment? You can then mount the ISO's instead of needing to burn 5 CD's VMWare Server is free, and so is ESXi.

Hope that sort of answers your question in a round about way!

Comment: "Being the SBS series was never released as a downloadable ISO (like all there other os's)" The ones I am using came from Technet where they are available as ISO's. Don't really want to use a VM yet(im using a basic dell desktop pc and i know esxi will not boot from it) I may eventually get there when i can put together a more dedicated system. 
I have reburned the disks at 1x and verified and will give the reload another shot.

Thanks!

Comment: Technet, of course! Dont they have a DVD copy of SBS R2 on there? would save burning 5 cd's.

ESXi 4 is very strict on the HCL side of things, but 3.5 is more flexible. I've got 2 ESXi 3.5 machines in old P4-3Gh HT's with 2/4G ram and only 80gb sata's. Off the original subject and question a bit. We'll see how you go with the reinstall... let me kow how you go, I'll be interest to know if it happens again.

Comment: Did the re-burn of the disks and the reinstall went good, no errors. I did not install exchange this time though.  Perhaps I will add it later.  I'm planning on jumping into the esxi realm soon, just waiting for a buddy who said he can get me an old hp rack server with scsi disks for free!! And no technet does not have a dvd! only cd images...beats me I guess they figure you'll use server 2008 and haven't bothered to update the iso's.
cheers!